# Creating a tooltip for every img in a div

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm having trouble creating and applying a tooltip to each of the images inside a div. The text of the tooltip should be the img's id. This seems like it would be fairly simple, so there must be something I am missing, or not understanding. Here's what I'm using:

```
$("#myDiv img").tooltip({   
        content:$(this).attr('id'),
        track:true
    });
```

Additionally, these images will be replaced depending on what the user clicks — once the images are deleted (by calling .empty on the containing div), do I need to delete the tooltips, or will they be automatically deleted from memory?

Sorry for the novice question!

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to get the id of all the img elements. Use .each to parse each element separately.

```
$("#myDiv img").each(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $this.tooltip({
        content: $this.attr('id'), // $this[0].id is faster
        track: true
    });
});
```

There is no need to remove the tooltip manually; the event bindings are deleted when the element is removed from the DOM.

Comment: This makes sense, but there is still no tooltip appearing when I hover over the images. This is the only code I have in the document pertaining to tooltips, should there be something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$("#myDiv").tooltip({
   items: "img",
    content: function() {
        var el = $(this);
        return el.attr( "id" ); // $this[0].id is faster
    },
    track: true
});
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zhb7mres/)</kbd>

Reference:

http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content